# What's the best practice when modifying twitter bootstrap javascript for your project

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In this particular case some of the popover functionality needs to be adapted to our particular needs.

The change itself is quite trivial, [it's a modification to this function](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L1369).

I just need to add another placement, but now I'm not exactly sure how to approach this.

One way would be adding a line to the bootstrap.js file in my repository, that works that has the serious disadvantage of having trouble when updating, I may remember now, but the next one to come after me might generate a hard bug to fix.

Another way I've thought of is extending the function but it might not be easy the way bootstrap is setup. As far as I understand since bootstrap functions are preceded with a plus (`+function(){}`), they're executed immediately and so I can't get in the way of that.

I've tried modifying this function `$.fn.tooltip.prototype.getCalculatedOffset` but while it does modify it correctly, the modified one never gets called since it's only called once.

It might be possible but I think the complications of this, outweighs how trivial the fix is (Unless I'm missing a more obvious approach).

Another idea would be forking bootstrap, but I'm not sure what would that accomplish, in the end I'm back with the same problem.

What's the most normal way to approach this? What are the best practices?

Comment: I would go for modifying the prototype ... but `the modified one never gets called since it's only called once.` does not make sense for me, as you are missing some reference of code and `it` (is it `the modified` or the other one?) :)

Comment: @AndreasNiedermair judging by kapa's answer you might be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the other answer but using the pop over function, just had to catch the right function!

```
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.getCalculatedOffse
```

http://jsfiddle.net/59Er7/3/

Answer (score 3):

A reference is saved to `Tooltip` as `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor` in [line 1472](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L1472):

```
$.fn.tooltip.Constructor = Tooltip
```

Modifying `$.fn.tooltip.Constructor.prototype.getCalculatedOffset` (of course not in the original file, but somewhere in your code) should affect the original `Tooltip`, which is ["instantiated"](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L1467) in [`$.fn.tooltip`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/dist/js/bootstrap.js#L1460).

I don't know whether this is best practice, but should work.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/59Er7/)

Comment: Hmm are you using calling tooltip instead of popover for any particular reason, I'm a little bit confused, if I call popover, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could it be that the tooltip plugin get's initialized before the popover is instantiated?

Comment: @Trufa Never used Bootstrap, so just tried to give a general solution, might have overlooked something :). Happy you got your answer.